# Returning an integer whose digits sum exactly to n

Tags: java, digits

My question is related to digits sum.

In a digit sum system, a digits sum of number 39 = 3 + 9 = 12.

However in my case, I would like to write a method where the user input 12, and the 
method will return 39, given that 39 is the smallest number to achieve digits sum of 12.

It will be good if we can discuss this in psuedo-code as I am more interested in learnign to develop a method/algorithm/formula to solve this puzzle.

The hint was given to use a queue. I have also tried the following:

number%9; number/9, which is close but does not seems to work for all cases.

An Example will be:

12%9 = 3

12/9 = 1; if( ans = 1, return 9)

therefore 3 and 9 will be 39. I know I am close but I tried using the same for numbers like 111, and this does not work anymore.

Comment: You last digit you can calculate, and the additional digits you can iterate over.

Comment: Is this homework? What code to you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest number is always of the form "x9...9999" where x is a single digit (possibly 0).

All you need to do is find:

- The value of x: `n % 9`
- How many 9s there are: `n / 9`.

For 111:

- `n % 9` is 3.
- `n / 9` is 12.

So the answer is 3999999999999.

Answer (score 1):

I think the smallest number `n` to have a digit sum equal to `k` will always be of the form

```
i99999
```

Where `i` is some digit.

Using this, you have

```
i = n % 9
j = floor(n / 9)
```

Then you construct your number by concatenating `i` then `9` `j` times.

For `n = 12` this yields `39`.

For `n = 111` this yields `3999999999999` (the `9` appears twelve times)